# MVVM View-First and DI IoC

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I would like to have my ViewModels to be instantiated (using a DI Container) and injected automatically in a View First approach. Is is possible?

If so, can you tell me a Framework for WPF that facilitates this mechanism?

Comment: did you look into MVVMLight?

Comment: Yes, I did. It uses SimpleIoC. Could I replace it with another IoC Container like Grace or Castle Windsor?

Comment: I haven't tried but I googled and saw Polaris, I am not sure if you can supply custom IOC